# Switch stuck in loop when passed incorrect type

Tags: c++

I have a switch case that expects an int, and when given an int, functions as expected. The int is taken in from the user using cin. If the user enters a letter, the function skips the cin on subsequent passes and continues around forever. How could entering the wrong type cause the program to stop waiting for cin?

If I enter the integer equivalent of a letter it works fine, 101 instead of e for example. I would expect it to just do a type conversion but I guess that's not what it does.

Simplest version of the code that reproduces the issue:

```
#include <iostream>

bool ui_switch();

int main() {
     while(ui_switch());
     return 0;
}

bool ui_switch() {
    int input;
    std::cout << "user > ";
    std::cin >> input;
    switch (input) {
    case 1:
        std::cout << "Exiting cin loop\n";
        return false;
        break;
    case 2:
        std::cout << "Not exiting loop\n";
        break;
    default:
        std::cout << "Help, I'm trapped in a loop!\n";   // if char entered
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: It seems to be the problem with `cin` setting bad bit after incorrect input. You need to check stream state and handle the error.

Comment: When you ask `std::cin` to read an integer value, then it will read an integer value. Anything else will not be read and will be left in the input buffer for you to read the next time. You need to [ignore](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) the rest of the line, and also need to [clear](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) the `failbit` from the [state flags](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate).